# Is there any way to make the ipad's front camera view angle wider?

Tags: ipad

Ipad mini front camera viewing angle is so small so if a group of people wants to be in the picture during chat , the ipad mini should be placed meters away. Is there any setting or any app that allow to change or control that? (something like ZOOM out for front camera)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no software setting to make the front camera wider than it already is. If it is fully zoomed out in the app, then it can't go any further.